# Can you detect the pattern?

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, anagram

### Read the title and identify

Airtight ace has, our "helicopter".

Cold manner hydra, implore "phi" law.

A only hardcore nut, he shook Mr. cell's.

Loathe "big" geezer, a Lonely Myth's.

Soon "sign" emerge, just "lire" game

Comment: These look a lot like anagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all anagrams of

> Famous fictional detectives and the authors who created them.

*Airtight ace has, our "helicopter".*

> [Hercule Poirot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercule_Poirot) ([Agatha Christie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agatha_Christie))

*Cold manner hydra, implore "phi" law.*

> [Philip Marlowe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Marlowe) ([Raymond Chandler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Chandler))

*A only hardcore nut, he shook Mr. cell's.*

> [Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes) ([Arthur Conan Doyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Conan_Doyle))

*Loathe "big" geezer, a Lonely Myth's*

> [Thomas Lynley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inspector_Lynley_Mysteries) ([Elizabeth George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_George))

*Soon "sign" emerge, just "lire" game*

> [Jules Maigret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Maigret) ([Georges Simenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Simenon))